# Relative Homology of $2$-genus Torus with a separating circle and a non-separating circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Compute Homology groups  $H_n(X,A)$ and $H_n(X,B)$ where $X$ is the 2-genus Torus, A is a separating Circle (as in the picture) and $B$ a non-separating Circle (as in the picture) [image]

My attempt :

Considering $(X,A)$ to be a good pair, used $H_n(X,A) = \widetilde{H_n}(X/A)$ and (seemed to me intuitively) $X/A \simeq T \lor T$ where $T=S^1 \times S^1$, Then I computed, $H_n(X,A)= \Bbb Z^4 \text{ if n = 1 , } \Bbb Z^2 \text{ if n = 2 , }  0 $ otherwise .

Similarly, obtained, $H_n(X,B) = \tilde{H_n}(X/B)$  and (seemed to me intuitively) $X/B \simeq T \lor S^1$ where $T=S^1 \times S^1$ . Then I computed, $H_n(X,B)= \Bbb Z^3 \text{ if n = 1 , } \Bbb Z \text{ if n = 2 , } 0 $ otherwise .

Are my arguments valid? Please point out mistakes!

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $H_n(X, A)=\tilde{H}_n(X/A)$ and similarly for $B$? Otherwise it seems to be ok, other than $X/B\simeq T\vee S^1$ could use a more rigorous argument.

Comment: @William Thanks for pointing out the typo. Are the homology groups correct? Kindly provide your argument which you suggest is more rigorous.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a more rigorous argument for showing this homotopy equivalence, but I do agree it's intuitively clear. An alternate way of computing the relative homology groups is with the long exact sequence of the pair, have you tried that? (The only potentially tricky part is determining the homology class of $A$ in $H_1(X)$, but the rest of the argument is formal.)

Answer (score 2):

You do have the right groups, and have not made any false statements. In order to make things less hand-wavy, you can compute the relative homology groups (almost) formally using the long exact sequence of the pair. The algebraic machinery lets us circumvent proving that $X/B\simeq T^2 \vee S^1$, which although it's intuitively clear it's hard to write down something rigorous without doing explicit manipulation of concrete objects, or computing homotopy groups and invoking Whitehead's Theorem.

Consider the sequence for $(X,A)$. Since $H_2(A) \cong 0$ and $H_0(A)\cong H_0(X)$ we get

$$0 \to H_2(X)\to H_2(X,A) \to H_1(A) \to H_1(X) \to H_1(X,A) \stackrel{0}{\to}\dots $$

We know that $H_2(X)\cong H_1(A)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_1(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}^4$. Denote the usual generators of $H_1(X)$ by $\alpha_1, \beta_1, \alpha_2, \beta_2$, where $\alpha_i$ is the circle going around the donut hole and $\beta_i$ is the circle going around the handle. Determining the map $H_1(A)$ to $H_1(X)$ amounts to determining the homology class of $A \subset X$; but we can see this is $0$ either by noticing it is a boundary, or by seeing that it's the commutator $\alpha_1 + \beta_1 - \alpha_1 - \beta_1 = 0$. Therefore $H_1(X,A)\cong H_1(X)$, and $H_2(X,A)$ fits in a short exact sequence

$$ 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to H_2(X,A) \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$

so must be $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

The sequence for $(X, B)$ is even easier, since the homology class of $B$ is just $\beta_2$. In other words the map $H_1(B)\to H_1(X)$ is an isomorphism onto one of the summands, therefore $H_1(X,B)\cong \mathbb{Z}^3$ and $H_2(X,A)\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks!
In the end of the answer it is written $H_2(X,A)$ and it should be $H_2(X,B)$.